# PHP SNMP extension is gone after php71 became php@7.1 with brew

Tags: php, homebrew, snmp

At Brew, they somehow moved php to Core https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/commit/ab5fffa7cf3b7dca77f2ffa6f6104fc09fd72221#diff-188d1e1be1dc7f3dea4ef64559d30f58

However, the SNMP extension is now missing. How to install it?

http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php71-snmp says Formula was removed
http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php72-snmp says the same for php 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone was struggling the same as I did and still want to use Homebrew, here's what I did: It's workaround but it works at least until the issue is resolved properly by Homebrew.

Fork https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/

**Reset the fork's `master` branch to latest working commit 5c90bd4** and force push to remote master on GitHub

**Untap Homebrew/homebrew-php**

```
brew untap homebrew/homebrew-php
```

**Tap your fork**

```
brew tap <your github username>/homebrew-php
```

After that when you run `brew search php` you'll see all good ol' php versions and extensions are available.

Or you can use this tap https://github.com/kabel/homebrew-php-ext as the [guy](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26004#issuecomment-377834506) from Issue I created put together

Answer (score 1):

According to [SMillerDev](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4827), this extension is now compiled into PHP.

> yes, the extensions are now compiled into PHP instead of shared. So you need to remove the config files for the old shared extensions.

and as you know, [he also said](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/4798):

> SNMP was excluded from the build because it crashes Apache.

but there is for now no open issues in [hombebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+php) about this.